# Sending an xml response back when a url is sent

Tags: java

my task is to check if my program is running fine on server or not.The scenario is like this :A URL is sent to the program that is continuously running and it is supposed to reply with a status OK if it is running fine.I am not able to understand the process how to do it.Can anyone explain.

Comment: Is your app deployed on webserver or it's just a plain Java program? If it's the former just write a servlet or something that takes a parameter and responds back OK with 200. If it's a application, you may use Jsch and pass the URL as you do on your local machine and look for response.

Comment: It is going to be deployed on web server.Can you please give me an example.That would be helpful

Comment: hmm... let me ask you for more clarification. Are you writing client side code i.e. the software that pings a URL on your server; or you wish to write the code on server side?

Comment: when someone hits the link to my servlet,it must ensure with a response that it is running.

Comment: It will just notify that it is running or not,nothing else.please help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I am assuming that you wanted to write some sort of health check page for your application. So here it goes.

```
package test.naishe.so;

public class HealthCheck extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 940861886429788526L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        int response = HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;

        boolean checkServices = true;
        //optional: assumming you wanted to do health check on various services (eg. DB service) and have a utility class for that
        checkServices = CheckServices.checkAll();

        if(checkServices)
            response = HttpServletResponse.SC_OK;

        String out =
            "<healthCheck>" +
            "<services>" +
                (checkServices?"OK":"ERROR")
            "</services>" +
            "</healthCheck>"
            ;

        resp.setStatus(response);
        resp.getWriter().println(out);

    }
}
```

in your web.xml add the following:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>healthCheck</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>test.naishe.so.HealthCheck</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>healthCheck</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/check_health</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

you can access this page from `<base_url>/check_health` on your local machine, `http://localhost[:port][/app_name]/check_health`